# Pymodbus multiple slaves error

Tags: python, modbus, rs485

I created two slaves and one master (RTU), and when I request something from slave id 1 both the slaves get the request, so one of them signals slave 1 doesnt exist and the other one recognizes the id and sends the data back. But when the data is sent back to the master the other slave tries to parse it which leads to an error.

SLAVE 2 LOG:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Started thread to serve client
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Client Connected [/dev/ttyUSB2:/dev/ttyUSB2]
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[3]
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:requested slave does not exist: 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x2 0x0 0x11 0x78 0x48
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

SLAVE 1 LOG:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Started thread to serve client
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Client Connected [/dev/ttyUSB1:/dev/ttyUSB1]
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[3]
DEBUG:pymodbus.datastore.context:validate[3] 1:1
DEBUG:pymodbus.datastore.context:getValues[3] 1:1
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:send: 01030200117848
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[3]
DEBUG:pymodbus.datastore.context:validate[3] 1:1
DEBUG:pymodbus.datastore.context:getValues[3] 1:1
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:send: 01030200117848
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0xa
```

Another log from SLAVE 2:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Started thread to serve client
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Client Connected [/dev/ttyUSB2:/dev/ttyUSB2]
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0xa 0x1 0x3 0x2 0x0 0x12 0x38 0x49
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[3]
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:requested slave does not exist: 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x2 0x0 0x12 0x38 0x49
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x1 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0xa 0x1 0x3 0x2 0x0 0x12 0x38 0x49
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x2 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0x39
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x2 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0x39
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x2 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0x39
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:0x2 0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x84 0x39
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[1]
ERROR:pymodbus.server.sync:Socket error occurred unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

How can I make slave 2 ignore the packets starting with 0x1?
I dont know if this is a bug in the library or Im doing something wrong.

This is the code for slave 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pymodbus.server.sync import StartSerialServer

from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext

from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100))

store2 = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [18]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100))

slaves_stores = {
    0x02: store2
}

context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=slaves_stores, single=False)

identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName  = 'Pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl   = 'http://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName   = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.0'

StartSerialServer(context, framer=ModbusRtuFramer, identity=identity, 
port='/dev/ttyUSB2', stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='O', 
ignore_missing_slaves=True, timeout=.005, baudrate=921600)
```

Comment: I can't see where you are assigning the slave IDs.

Comment: @Ronaldo that should be the slaves_stores. It actually works, but when I switch from reading from slave 1 to slave 2 it stops working. Reading from just either of them works though.

Comment: There is a line in the slave 2 log that althought I don't know what is happening may help. It seems slave 2 is interpreting the first byte of the slave 1's response as a function code, not as the unit id. That's why we see the "Factory Request [1]" line in the log. I will take a look at pyModbus code and try to find out what's going on.

Comment: I have noticed its not only the first byte tho, ill add another log.